# Vuejs + VeeValidate passing paramets to child component

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I have created a component called Month where I pass some props:

```
<template>
  <select :id="id" :name="id" :class="extraClasses" :v-validate="{required: req}">
    <option v-if="def" selected disabled :value="null">{{def}}</option>
    <option v-if="!def" selected disabled :value="null">Month</option>
    <option v-for="(month, index) in months" :key="index" :value="pad(index)">{{month}}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

They all work correctly if I call it with something such as:

```
<Month id="dob_month" extraClasses="month" def="Initial month" />
```

However when I try to pass the validation part VeeValidate seems to ignore it:

```
<Month id="dob_month" req="true" />
```

Is there a way I can pass the validation to the children without using a message bus so that I can do something similar to this in the parent:

```
<fieldset id="dob" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('dob_day') || errors.has('dob_month') || errors.has('dob_year') }">
  <legend class="a-required">Date of Birth</legend>
  <input type="hidden" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" />
  <select id="dob_day" name="dob_day" v-validate="'required'">
    <option selected disabled value="">Day</option>
    <option v-for="day in monthDays" :key="day" :value="day">{{day}}</option>
  </select>
  <Month id="dob_month" req=true />
  <Year id="dob_year" req="true" />
</fieldset>
```

Or will I not be able to get **errors** populated/propagated correctly between parent and child?

Comment: not clear what u passing and what is not working

Comment: Sorry, what I pass in the parent to the child is `<Month id="dob_month" req="true" />` and the child component has: `<select :id="id" :name="id" :class="extraClasses" :v-validate="{required: req}">` however it doesn't seem to actually pay attention to the req prop

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use : for v-validate. Its value already interpolated inside vee-validate.
Something like this should work:

```
  <select :id="id" :name="id" :class="extraClasses" v-validate="{required: req}">
```

See this codepen for example with min rule and local variable https://codepen.io/aldarund/pen/LrmaKz

Comment: Thank you! Such a minor change